# How can i get sql data without repeating?

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't want data to be repeated like this

**SQL Query and tables information:**

[image]

**SQL Data:**

[image]

I want Results to be like this
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjUUW.png)

Comment: Please note you won't receive a price for being as most short and unprecise as possible. Your output does not include doubled data. Please show your expected outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Like what u get repeating ? please update your description with examples.

Use `SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, ... FROM table_name;`

pls check your result as u get different data based on date.GoodsName repeated bcz it different date.

Comment: DISTINCT will likely slow down the query and should not be proposed as solution without knowing what exactly is the problem. Mostly, DISTINCT is not really required, but used by beginners when they fail to write a correct GROUP BY or so.

Comment: @Jonas Metzler i accept your suggestion.